# Sharing data in the same library in different process

Tags: c#, data-sharing

I am working on a library included in different services.

A specific service receive a message, after receiving that message my library reads it, then needs to save some data from this message.

In another service, after it receives a specific message, my library has to create a message with the data from the first message.

How can i do this ?

Obviously, i don't want to use a file where i put these informations, i'd like it to be well-done. I kept a look at the WCF Inter-Process sharing datas, but as everything is done inside my library, it doesn't work well... Any ideas?

Comment: Is this going to be used in a threaded application?

Comment: Yeah but everything is already thread safe.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're wanting to do here.  Are the two services supposed to be able to affect each other?

Answer (score 1):

I don't propose this as an answer but since I don't have the rights to commment, this will have to do.

It might be your library but that's irrelevant - you want to pass information from one .net process to another. And as far as I know you'll need to use some form of communication to do that - .net remoting, TCPIP or some other type of comms.

Quite a while ago I had two Windows apps communicating through shared memory and, if your apps are all running on the same machine, this might be worth a look. These links may help: https://sharedmemory.codeplex.com/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx

When a message arrives, you will need your apps to know that there is data available for them. If they are running on separate machines you will have to have some sort of comms, but if they are on the same machine a system wide event may be the way to go.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfk7eby4(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps!

Regards,

Adam.

Comment: I actually works on a very big application including a lot of services. And my library can't be something else than a library. This part where it takes informations from one message received in one service to create a new message in another service is just a little part of what it actually does. If i can't figure out a solution, i will use files but i have the feeling i can find a better solution.